# Bootstrap Vue Sidebar Scroll back to where the toggle button is after close the sidebar

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I want to use this as a toggle sidebar when the viewport is mobile.
*note my page is a Linear Page so when I click on the nav link it should be scroll to where the link point to.
It goes to where the link point to but after i click to close the sidebar it just scroll back to where  the toggle button is.
here what my sidebar look like.

```
<div style="margin:2000px 0">
<b-button v-b-toggle.sidebar-1>Toggle Sidebar</b-button>
<b-sidebar id="sidebar-1" title="Sidebar" shadow>
  <div class="px-3 py-2">
    <p>
      Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis
      in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
    </p>
    <b-img src="https://picsum.photos/500/500/?image=54" fluid thumbnail></b-img>
  </div>
</b-sidebar>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<b-sidebar>` returns focus to the element which opened it, which is causing your page to scroll to it.

There's currently no built-in way to disable this behavior. However in the next version (`2.17.0`), there will be a new prop `no-enforce-focus`, which can be used to disable the sidebars built-in focus functionality.

Comment: thank for the head up good to know. I guess for now I gonna use css to make it for now.